# Emacs remote compile with multiple commands using TRAMP

Tags: emacs, tramp

So I have no trouble using remote compile if the Makefile is in the same directory as the file I'm editing using `M-x compile`. The problem is if I need to switch to the root project directory, it tells me that the path cannot be found via the `CDPATH` environment variable. To get around this I simply just opened a `dired` buffer in the project root directory and compiled from there. Due to a restructuring we now need to call `source` on a file in that directory for some configuration options and attempting to do `source Sourceme && make` which works locally results in a file not found on the Sourceme file. Is there a way around this in TRAMP? I've tried the common suggestions and already have ControlMaster in ssh set but even with `M-x remote-compile` it always prompts for a password even with ControlMaster set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the compile command to `bash -c "first_cmd && second_cmd..."` seems to be a quick hack around it.